# How to add checkbox to wxGrid cell?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a bunch of data organized by rows. In the first cell of each row, I want to have a checkbox, so the user can go through and select certain rows.

I know I could make the user use CTRL + click each row, but I rather have checkboxs as this is a feature to be used a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use checkboxes for any cell by explicitly setting it up to use `wxGridCellBoolRenderer` and `wxGridCellBoolEditor`, but the simplest way to use them is to just use boolean values for the cells in the first column, i.e. define a custom `wxGridTable` subclass which would return `wxGRID_VALUE_BOOL` from its `GetTypeName()` for the first column.
Then the checkboxes will be used automatically.

I'm sure you can find some examples in Python as well, but I can only point you to [C++ grid sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/grid/griddemo.cpp), which should hopefully translate to Python in a straightforward way.